# select row having maximum column data

Tags: sql-server, select

I have more than 1 rows in a table that belong to same ID.

I want to select row where more columns contain data .

eg.

My data looks like this

```
select * from my_table where id=1

PK   Id   Col1   Col2   Col3   Col4   Col5   Col6   Col7   Col8   Col9   Col10
101  1    NULL   NULL   NULL   XX     NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL
102  1    NULL   NULL   NULL   XX     YY     NULL   ZZ     NULL   NULL   NULL
103  1    NULL   AA     NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL
104  1    NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   BB     NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL
105  1    NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   CC     NULL   NULL
```

I want query which will give me Output like this for id=1 : -

```
PK   Id   Col1   Col2   Col3   Col4   Col5   Col6   Col7   Col8   Col9   Col10
102  1    NULL   NULL   NULL   XX     YY     NULL   ZZ     NULL   NULL   NULL
```

Comment: Normalise your data structures.

Comment: @podiluska totally agree with you

Comment: @podiluska: Even I am agree with you. But I can't do so. So I have to take it as it is.

Comment: Do your rows even have an Primary Key?

Comment: @podiluska : OK. I have one now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where pk is your primary key...

```
select * 
from YourBadlyStructuredTable
where pk in (
    select top 1 pk from YourBadlyStructuredTable
    unpivot (col for z in (col1,col2,col3, ...))u
    where id=1
    group by pk
    order by COUNT(*) desc
)
```

If you can't specify your column names...

```
select 
    top 1 
    HorribleTable.* 
from
(
    select
        xmldata.value('(/x2/@PK)[1]','int') as PK1,
        xmldata.value('(/x2/@Id)[1]','int') as ID1,
        xmldata.value('count(/x2/@*)','int') as cnt
        from
        (
    select      
        t.x.query('.') as xmldata               
    from
        (   select convert(xml,(select * from HorribleTable for xml raw('x2'))) as x1) v
            cross apply
        v.x1.nodes('/x2') t(x)
    ) v
) v
    inner join HorribleTable on v.PK1 = HorribleTable.pk
where ID1 = 1 
order by cnt desc
```

Comment: I like the table name and I will definitely tell the same to our DBA.

Comment: I can see the solution working . But actually I have a table with 53 columns and I want a generic solution to this kind of issue. I do not want to mention all the columns explicitly.

Comment: v.PK1 is getting NULL value. So did not return result.

Comment: Try it now - XML attributes are case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
with cte as (select  *,case when col1 is not null then 1 else 0 end+
          case when col2 is not null then 1 else 0 end+
          case when col3 is not null then 1 else 0 end+
          case when col4 is not null then 1 else 0 end+
          case when col5 is not null then 1 else 0 end+
          case when col6 is not null then 1 else 0 end+
          case when col7 is not null then 1 else 0 end+
          case when col8 is not null then 1 else 0 end+
          case when col9 is not null then 1 else 0 end+
          case when col10 is not null then 1 else 0 end as col_count
  from my_table  where id=1)
  select * from cte where col_count =(select MAX(col_count) from cte)
```

Comment: I want that row not the maximum value for each column.

Comment: I can see the solution working . But actually I have a table with 53 columns and I want a generic solution to this kind of issue. I do not want to mention all the columns explicitly

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH CTE as (    
select pk,isnull(col1,'')+isnull(col2,'')+isnull(col3,'')+isnull(col4,'')+isnull(col5,'')+
    isnull(col6,'')+isnull(col7,'')+isnull(col8,'')+isnull(col9,'')+isnull(col10,'') as res
    from tbl4 where id=1)


select * from tbl4 where pk in(select pk from CTE where len(res)=(select max(len(res)) from CTE))
```